# Getting most recent execution by job via RunDeck API

Tags: rundeck

Is there a more efficient way to get the most recent execution of every job in a RunDeck project that by (1) querying for the job list and then (2) querying for the `max: 1` execution list of each job in serial?

Answer (score -1):

The most efficient way to get all jobs last execution is getting the IDs, putting the IDs in a list, and then calling the execution endpoint based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66910429/10426011) answer.

I made a working bash example using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), take a look:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# protocol
protocol="http"

# basic rundeck info
rdeck_host="localhost"
rdeck_port="4440"
rdeck_api="40"
rdeck_token="RQvvsGODsP8YhGUw6JARriXOAn6s6OQR"

# project name
project="ProjectEXAMPLE"

# first get all jobs (of ProjectEXAMPLE project)
jobs=$(curl -s --location "$protocol://$rdeck_host:$rdeck_port/api/$rdeck_api/project/$project/jobs" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: $rdeck_token" --header "Content-Type: application/json" | jq -r .[].id)

# just for debug, print all jobs ids
echo $jobs

# then iterates on the jobs id's and extracting the last succeeded execution
for z in ${jobs}; do
    curl -s --location "$protocol://$rdeck_host:$rdeck_port/api/$rdeck_api/job/$z/executions?status=succeeded&max=1" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: $rdeck_token" --header "Content-Type: application/json" | jq
done
```

Sadly doesn't exist a direct way to do that in a single call.

Comment: I think that call will still only pertain to specific job?

Comment: I updated my answer, I left a bash example that gets all last succeeded execution from all jobs (from a specific project). Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is what I am already doing. This is quite slow when you have hundreds of jobs, so my question is really if there is a more efficient option than this--ideally a single API call. But it seems perhaps that is not possible.